# How can I add to Sign in process in Azure B2C one next step

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I created an Azure B2C environment based on the starter pack provided by Microsoft. I currently have the default UserJourney with `Id="SignUpOrSignIn"`. To this User Journey, I am trying to add an additional page where, after clicking login, the user will see a page with static content containing additional information and a only one continue button (I think it should be an additional orchestrationstep). After clicking continue button token should be returned.

[Used starter Pack Policies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNENJ.png)

And after that the user will be logged in. Unfortunately, the attempts made so far have been unsuccessful. Could I ask for a hint on what to do to achieve this next step?

```xml
<UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn">
  <OrchestrationSteps>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when in the token. -->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />

  </OrchestrationSteps>
  <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
</UserJourney>
```